# Aligning image to the corner of a table cell in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I want to align an image to the corner of a table cell in Blogger.
I found a way to do it in a simple Html page:

```
<td width="20%" valign="top" align="right"  style="vertical-align: top;" >
```

but when I use this in Blogger , it doesn't work.

The image is always in the center no matter what are the values of valign and align. I think that I need to override a specific style or disable it but I don't know how what to do as I'm a beginner.
Any help ?

Comment: post an image of what it looks like and some html code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delete other tr tags on above. Because they are pushing image div to middle.